# firefox screen issue with click() method

Tags: javascript, jquery

The question has to do with Firefox refreshing the browser window to 100% when a function is called.
If the browser view is at say, 75%, and I use .click method on a link - the page refreshes at 100% THEN the function executes. Safari executes the function without refreshing the window.

The code now looks like:

```
function hideFlag(){

    $("#ftm").click(function () { 

    var stageWidth = $("#window_div").width();
    if (stageWidth <= 1200){

        $( "#window_div" ).animate({
            width: 1250,
          opacity: ".8",
        }, 1000 );
        $( "#flagDiv" ).animate({
          opacity: "0",
          }, 1000 ); 
        }
    else{
        $( "#window_div" ).animate({
        width: 500,
        opacity: ".6",
        }, 1000 );
        $( "#flagDiv" ).animate({
        opacity: "1",
        }, 1000 );
        }   
    });
}
```

In Firefox, if my browser view is zoomed out to 75% and I replace the .click() method with .mouseenter, the divs animate without the screen redrawing or resizing on mouseenter. I don't understand the difference between the click() and mouseenter() implementations.

Solved it.

It was far simpler than I thought. Proper use of the "return false;" argument on the click method
solved my problem. Revised code is as follows:

```
function hideFlag(){

            $("#ftm").click(function () { 
                var stageWidth = $("#window_div").width();
                if (stageWidth <= 1200){
                    $( "#window_div" ).animate({
                        width: 1250, 
                        opacity: ".8", 
                        }, 1000 ); return false;
                    $( "#flagDiv" ).animate({
                        opacity: "0",
                        }, 1000 ); return false;
                    }
                else{
                    $( "#window_div" ).animate({
                        width: 500, 
                        opacity: ".6", 
                    }, 1000 );return false;
                    $( "#flagDiv" ).animate({
                        opacity: "1", 
                    }, 1000 );return false;
                }   
            });
}
```

Thanks all for the help.

Answer (score 0):

<sup>Not that this a direct answer to your question, but it's rather long for a comment.</sup>

You're using jQuery. I think you're missing the point of the whole cross-browser-library thing. Change

```
stageWidth = document.getElementById("window_div").clientWidth
```

to

```
stageWidth = $("#window_div").width()
```

no browser-specific code needed. There also no need for that `addEventHandler` function when using jQuery. It takes care of the differences between browsers so that you don't have to. That means you can change the `setUpClickHandler` function to this:

```
function setUpClickHandler() {
    $('#ftm').click(hideFlag);
    $('#ath').click(showFlag);
}
```

and change `showFlag` to this:

```
function showFlag(e){
    $('#flagDiv').show();
}
```

and change

```
addEventHandler(window, "load", setUpClickHandler, false);
```

to

```
$(window).load(setUpClickHandler);
```

Comment: Thanks Matt. That's very helpful and solves my style.pixelWidth vs clientWidth issue. Unfortunately, it still leaves me clueless as to the screen resize/zoom issue I'm seeing in Firefox. Thanks for your help.

Comment: your additional code changes are much less verbose than my previous code. Screen zoom issue persists in Firefox, though Safari executes flawlessly.